# URL working on localhost but not found on test server in Laravel

Tags: laravel, request

I have in my web.php a request as below:

```
Route::get('emp_listing/{region}/{start_date}/{end_date}/{supervisor?}/{emp_status?}', 'EmpListingController@get_emp_to_excel');
```

and in js I have the line below:

```
function getBaseUrl() {
    var l = window.location;
    var base_url = l.protocol + "//" + l.host + "/" + l.pathname.split('/')[1] + "/" + l.pathname.split('/')[2];
    return base_url;
}

function getEmpExcelData(){
    var base_url = getBaseUrl();

    window.location.href = base_url + "/emp_listing/" + region + '/' + start_date + '/' + end_date + '/' + supervisor + '/' + emp_status;

}
```

On my local computer when I click the button, the link in js execute successfully however on test server, it says

```
Firefox can’t find the file at http://xx.69.1x.xx/emp/public/emp_listing/1/2017-11-01/2017-11-30/0/null
```

I don't understand why this works locally but doesn't work on test server.

Every other request is working fine

Comment: Can you post the URL that is working on your localhost?

Comment: Are the databases in sync or the same?  Ie, is the data the same? Cause null at the end tells me that it can't find something.

Comment: It looks like it is looking for supervisor with ID 0. Or emp_status is null.

Answer (score 0):

After digging, I found my problem. I am using [Maatwebsite\Excel](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel) package. On my local server, the php zip extension is installed but not on test server. So I have installed the extension like below:

```
 sudo yum install php-pecl-zip
```

After installing, everything now works fine.